# How can Franklin not lose the game because of Lamar?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, mods

I am working on a research project based on GTAV (Grand Theft Auto 5-GTA5) on PC. However, I need to use teleport feature of Script Hook V which when I use it and go anywhere, I lose the mission because it tells me I abandoned Lamar. Also when I am just playing normally and grab the car (after someone talked to Michael) using Y and then press on gas pedal and follow Lamar, after less than 1 minutes, it just tells me I lost the mission because of losing Lamar. How can I get rid of this whole Lamar thing and play solo? Seems for teleporting, I do really need to play solo else Lamar will be left out. I am also planning to run the scrips (C Sharp and Lua scripts) using Script Hook V .NET and for so teleporting is needed.

- I bought the game from Rockstar and is run on Windows 10 x64 in 64-bit mode.
- Thanks to Script Hook V and pressing F4, teleport feature works but I lose the mission right after going to the new place.

Here's the car driving part that I lose because of Lamar:

Comment: If you're actually coding, you should probably be asking this at GameDev.SE, not here.

Comment: not coding! Just using the tools

Comment: So far as I can tell, Script Hook V .NET allows you to write scripts in .NET.  Which is definitely coding.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to say, if I want to use the mods in script hook v, I need to play single-player which is what I selected. However, I am losing the game because of the other player (Lamar). How can I play independently of Lamar?

Comment: I think you're not understanding the game rails here. Franklin has to follow Lamar and stay within X distance or FAIL triggers. Stand still, teleport, etc - if the player falls outside X, FAIL. You need to either prpgress, revert to a save on an easier mission to clear it and go back to free-roam.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn Gordon, that makes sense to me that I have to follow Lamar to pass this stage. I wonder if there's a part that I can teleport (which part?) and my progress wouldn't be related to following Lamar hence I can teleport? Basically in which stages am I allowed to teleport?

Comment: Also I realized the "Invisble" mode didn't work as shown in "Script Hook V" menu and I wonder how it works for others as shown in gameplays in YouTube. Even though I was invisible, I was punched at by the guy who approaches my red car and eventually killed.

Comment: The game works on mixture of missions and free roam. To have a relatively unconditional experience you'll have to complete the mission successfully (or fail enough to be asked if you want to skip) and go to a free roam portion of the game. If you're just starting it will take a bit of time to go through all the character intros and basic story setup

Comment: I see, thanks! It was informative. Are we told that it's a free roam portion in the beginning of such episodes?

Comment: Not in a strict sense, but you "feel" it. You will have a sense of "um, what now?" because you'll notice a lack of direction regarding what you need to do. It's not of what to look for, but what you'll notice is missing that is your tip off. A couple of hours in through constant play and you'll have no problem naturally identifying the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete the mission (and any other auto-triggered missions) before you can free roam.